# HR scheduled an interview on Labor Day. I agreed, but forgot about Labor Day. Should I email confirming that the interview is indeed on Labor Day?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, united-states

Title says it. After finishing my first interview, HR requested a second Skype interview on Monday September 7th. I agreed to it yesterday. I realized today that Monday is Labor Day. I personally am okay with doing an interview on Labor Day, but because I forgot about Labor Day, I'm thinking now that HR might've forgot about it as well.

Should I email HR tonight just saying,

"Hi, just to confirm, the interview is on Monday (Labor Day), right? I'm personally okay with it but I just wanted to confirm that the hiring manager is also okay with it."

Or do you think it is not needed?

Edit: Company is in the United States. Interview is on Monday September 7th.

Comment: I think you should reword it to just say, "Hello, I wanted to send an email confirming our interview on Monday, 9/7 at 9am. Thank you." The other stuff looks unprofessional. A courtesy email is not unheard of and you may get one from them as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Absolutely email and ask.  You don't want to be waiting around for a Skype call that isn't forthcoming.

I'd word it more like:

> Hi, I'd just like to confirm our Skype interview on Monday at [time].  I thought I'd better check given that Monday is Labor Day.  I am available at that time, so I'll talk to you then!
>
> Kind regards, user112321123

I am of course assuming that the company is located somewhere that celebrates Labor Day on that day as well.

Comment: As my answer, asking the question can't hurt :)

Comment: It is almost always better to take action than to do nothing and hope for the best. Asking won't hurt and it may help.

Comment: The interviewer might be equally surprised that someone scheduled him to do an interview on a bank holiday, and not very happy about it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes ask, a short note is always a good idea the business day before an interview to confirm everybody is on the same page. You are lucky because you have a perfect excuse for the note.

Not all US business give their employees off on labor day. For example hospitals, restaurants, stores...